# Why is useState imported in {} in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In react hooks, I found that the import statement uses:
import { useState } from 'react';
Why does it use the {} around the useState?

Comment: This is not React-specific, that's just how you import a non-default export.

Comment: To avoid confusions like this I do recommend you to first learn some javascript basics before digging into libraries and frameworks.

Comment: I don't think object destructuring is basic JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You use curly braces to import named modules, that is if it was exported using code like this:

```
const myModule = "example exported value";

export { myModule };
```

You can import module without curly braces if it was exported as a default module, that is:

```
const myModule = "example exported value";

export default myModule;
```

So to answer your question. Default React object is exported as a default and other modules are exported as named modules.

Here's an example on how you can do it yourself:
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-ride-g893e?file=/src/index.js

You can read more about importing and exporting modules in JavaScript on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export